# Change Home page from WordPress to Xenforo

Tags: wordpress, web, xenforo

I have a website which has both WordPress and Xenforo forum and both has individual home pages. The Xenforo is installed inside /community directory and WordPress in default directory. Now the website's home page is WordPress, but I want to change it to Xenforo's home page. I tried redirecting, but it is a bit slow. Is there any other way to do it without redirecting?

I redirected from the WordPress homepage to Xenforo, but it was slow and I even tried to run the Xenforo app from the WordPress directory, it did not work properly (duh!!!). I want a way to change the home page without redirecting.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not about changing home pages, try: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/